# populate python qt widget with items from class

Tags: python, qt

I've written a script here in python which consists of a class I made called 'Profile'. Each profile has a 'Name' and list of 'Plugin Names'

I need help getting the list to populate the Ui. When the ui is initiated I want the dropdownlist to be populated with the 'Names' of each profile. Then as the 'Profile' is selected, the listbox be populate with the appropriate plugin names. I've commented out the profiles as I wasn't sure how to properly get them working.

Hope that is clear explaining.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    class Profile(object):
        def __init__(self, name, plugins):
            self.name = name
            self.plugins = plugins

    def initUI(self):

        # UI CONTORLS
        uiProfiles = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        uiPluginList = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        uiLaunch = QtGui.QPushButton("Launch")

        # STYLING
        uiLaunch.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        uiLaunch.resize(uiLaunch.sizeHint())
        uiLaunch.setMinimumHeight(30)

        # UI LAYOUT
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(uiProfiles, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(uiPluginList, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(uiLaunch, 3, 0)

        self.setLayout(grid) 
        self.setGeometry(300, 500, 600, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('3ds Max Launcher')
        self.resize(400,150)
        self.show()


        # profiles = [
        #   Profile(name="3ds Max Workstation", plugins=["FumeFX", "Afterworks", "Multiscatter"]),
        #   Profile(name="3ds Max All Plugins", plugins=["FumeFX"]),
        #   Profile(name="3ds Max Lite", plugins=["default 3ds max"]),
        # ]

        # for p in profiles:
        #   uiProfiles.addItem(p.name)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a few problems. Your MainWindow never got shown. You were defining the Profile class inside your Example class (instead of on it's own). You also had no event function that did something when the user changed the profile list.

I made put the profile names into a [QStringListModel](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstringlistmodel.html). This means that any changes to the names in the model will automatically update the widget. You don't have to do it this way, but it's easier in larger projects and not really any harder to do.

I also connected a function to the event that occurs when the value of the combo box is changed. You will need to make another event function and connect it to a launch button event as well.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui    


class Profile(object):
    def __init__(self, name, plugins):
        self.name = name
        self.plugins = plugins


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.profiles = [Profile(name="3ds Max Workstation", plugins=["FumeFX", "Afterworks", "Multiscatter"]),
                    Profile(name="3ds Max All Plugins", plugins=["FumeFX"]),
                    Profile(name="3ds Max Lite", plugins=["default 3ds max"])]

        profile_names = [p.name for p in self.profiles]

        # make a model to store the profiles data in
        # changes to data will automatically appear in the widget
        self.uiProfilesModel = QtGui.QStringListModel()
        self.uiProfilesModel.setStringList(profile_names)

        # UI CONTORLS
        self.uiProfiles = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        self.uiPluginList = QtGui.QListWidget(self)
        self.uiLaunch = QtGui.QPushButton("Launch")

        # associate the model to the widget
        self.uiProfiles.setModel(self.uiProfilesModel)

        # connect signals
        self.uiProfiles.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.on_select_profile)

        # STYLING
        self.uiLaunch.setToolTip('This is a <b>QPushButton</b> widget')
        self.uiLaunch.resize(self.uiLaunch.sizeHint())
        self.uiLaunch.setMinimumHeight(30)

        # UI LAYOUT
        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(self.uiProfiles, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.uiPluginList, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.uiLaunch, 3, 0)

        self.setLayout(grid) 
        self.setGeometry(300, 500, 600, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('3ds Max Launcher')
        self.resize(400,150)
        self.show()

        # run once to fill in list
        self.on_select_profile(0)

    def on_select_profile(self, index):

        # clear list
        self.uiPluginList.clear()

        # populate list        
        for plugin in self.profiles[index].plugins:
            self.uiPluginList.addItem(plugin)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much Figs, this does exactly what I was after and i appreciate you explaining things as well as making sure to comment the code. Thank you.